# Form redirecting to wrong controller method upon submitting Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have created a user settings page with an input field to allow the connected user to change their username. However, when changing the name in the input field and submitting the form, the page refreshes with the old username. I figured out that the request was going to my show method instead of the update method. The weird part is that if I remove the route linked to the update method (PUT), I get the following error.

> The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

But if I leave it, the request takes the show route (GET) instead.

**Form**

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <form method="POST" action="/user/{{ $user->id }}">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ $user->name }}"/>

                <!-- Sends to show instead of update ! -->
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-custom" value="Save name">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/user/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
Route::put('/user/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
```

**UserController.php**

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function show(User $user)
    {

        if (!$this->isLoggedIn($user->id)) {
            return back()->withInput();
        }

        return view('users.profile', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        // dump($user);die; (This doesn't work, I'm only going through show())
        if (!$this->isLoggedIn($user->id)) {
            return back()->withInput();
        }

        $user->name = $request->get('name');

        $user->save();

        return view('users.show', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function isLoggedIn($id)
    {
        if ($id == Auth::user()->id) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try cleaning the routes, and caches?

Comment: Changing the form and clearing routes and caches didn't change anything :(
I used the following commands to clear routes and cache :

`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan route:clear`

Comment: What debugging have you done? Check your browser's network inspector to see what values are being sent. You should clear all caches with `artisan optimize:clear` which will also clear the view cache where your form might be cached.

Comment: So far I just tried to change routes / use dump() in my controller in the different methods. I also ensured the right id was sent and that the cache was cleared. I noticed the following error in my console, after submitting the form upon page refresh : 
`POST https://o104379.ingest.sentry.io/api/5495040/envelope/?sentry_key=31f33ef1a1a74d32a00749c3718b640d&sentry_version=7 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` but it looks unrelated.

Comment: I noticed that when running `php artisan route:list` my user routes have no name, the Name column is empty (no user.show or user.update for example). Maybe that's the cause of the problem ? Not sure why this happened

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the issue :

It was coming from the validation rules in my request. The request was expecting a name, email and password while I was sending a name alone for update.

Changed the rules for update and it works correctly now.

Cheers